# I am trying to add two apps url in main project url to list defaultrouter with same end point but it's only showing one

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-urls

Here is the code from first apps urls.py

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r"users",ProfileViewSet, basename='users')


urlpatterns = [
    path("", include(router.urls)),
]
```

Here is the code from second apps urls.py

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'articles', av.ArticleViewSet, basename='articles')

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
]
```

I am trying to achieve this in main project urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
path("api/", include('users.api.urls')),
path("api/", include('mainapp.api.urls')),
```

]

It's only showing one url on Api Root

{
"users": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/users/"
}

Please help to achieve this.
I want to show both **users** and **articles** DefaultRouter.

Like this.

**{
"users": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/users/",
"articles": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/articles/"
}**

Comment: That is because the root to show the views answers with the router from `users`.

Comment: It's not clear to me. How can i achieve this ? Thanks